# Can such a UI be created with unmanaged Visual C++ and MFC?

Tags: windows, mfc

I need to create a shoebox-style native Windows app in C++. A good example of such a UI would be CleanMyPC: [image: example screenshot]

I've tried the various options of the MFC App wizard in Visual Studio 2019 to see what that would give, but it's either document-based (SDI), or too limited (dialog-style). The closest was an empty Win32 app, which just displays a menu bar and a blank window beneath it. At least it matches the Windows style. But that would mean using bare Win32 API, which doesn't seem like a good idea.

Can a UI like in the screenshot be created with MFC? If so, would that be a reasonable approach? Can MFC be effectively used in a non-document-style, non-dialog-style UI like this?

I understand that there's heavy customization of the controls going on in the screenshot; the question is can it be done with MFC?

It looks like the left sidebar and the right details areas could be made of customized list controls. I'll be looking into how a dialog-based sample app arranges the window, so that no document stuff is involved, but without immediate termination on a button click.

Comment: Not an MFC expert here, I'm sure it can be done, but I'm sure it could be done even easier by using .NET. If you have native libraries you need to use, you could still do that, but have a .NET UI with an unmanaged backend.

Comment: @CJohnson I imagine it would be easier in .NET, but in this case I need C++ both in the UI and on the backend.

Comment: Well, I think you are just going to have to sit down and learn MFC then. There is a wealth of knowledge on the internet on how to customize MFC controls.

Comment: I think this is the definitive book: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1572316950/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_hsch_vapi_taft_p1_i0

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation. Learning is not the problem, I'm just looking for a general approach recommendation at this point. I've updated the question a bit.

Comment: Yes you can use a dialog based application. You won't gain anything from complexity of SDI application.

Comment: MFC is a resource management wrapper over the Windows API (plus framework). Anything you can do in the Windows API, you can do in MFC. If you can limit your target platform to Windows 10 (1903) and up, I'd probably look into [XAML islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands). It's still all native code (when using [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/winrt)), but uses the Windows 10 Presentation stack. It's just way easier to customize your UI with XAML.